# Is there a way to forget node names between TikZ pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have a document with several TikZ pictures in it.  I generally use simple names for the nodes such as:

```
\node (A) at ..... 
\node (B) at .....
```

and so forth.  Because of this I have name clashes between the various pictures.  That's generally not a problem.  However I find myself in a position where I may or may not have defined a certain node within a given picture.  So I use the following snippet to test whether the node has been defined:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%%
  \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately this fails if I've already created a node by the same name in another picture.

Is there a way to scope the definitions of nodes or is there a way to undefine nodes once you no longer need them?

**P.S.**

I'm aware that I could embed each picture in a `standalone` file and import it using `\includegraphics`.  Unfortunately, this approach will not work for the document I'm creating.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%%
  \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}


There's no node \textbf{D} here, so I draw a triangle:\par
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
%  \coordinate (D) at (0,1);

  \ifnodedefined{D}
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C,D} {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C}   {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }

\end{tikzpicture}




There is a node \textbf{D} here, so I draw a square:\par
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (D) at (0,1);

  \ifnodedefined{D}
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C,D} {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C}   {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }

\end{tikzpicture}





There isn't supposed to be a node \textbf{D} here.  I'm expecting a
triangle, but get a square.\par
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
%  \coordinate (D) at (0,1);

  \ifnodedefined{D}
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C,D} {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C}   {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a Minimum Working Example... or non-Working, in this case...

Comment: @cfr While I'm not opposed to posting a MWE, I'm not sure what would be gained here.  The question seems simple and straight-forward, "Can you undefine a node?"

Comment: I asked because when I tried to create a MWE, I just reused the same node name in the two pictures and had no trouble. No errors, no missing nodes. So clearly something more is required for it to be a problem and I was wondering what. Even if I use relative positioning and put the first `myothernode` left of the first `mynode` and the second `myothernode` right of the second `mynode`, it still all works.

Comment: That is, I thought you had to do something special to get `tikz` to *remember* between pictures and that the *default* was to forget.

Comment: @cfr Ah!  I see what you mean.  OK.  I'll post something to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It just occurs to me that 'fails` is ambiguous. Did you mean: that command says the node *is* defined if it is defined in a different picture but not the present one, whereas you want it to say it is defined only if it is defined in the present one? If you put it in a `standalone` file and `\input` the file, does that avoid the problem? (That is, not using `\includegraphics` but the way `standalone` handles things by default.)

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the question. (I was originally really confused possibly because my `tikz` skills are similar to a bored snail's. No offence meant to bored snails.)

Answer (score 7):

It seems I practically answered my question by the way I asked it:

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand\aeundefinenode[1]{%%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@ns@#1\endcsname\relax
  \else
    \typeout{===>Undefining node "#1"}%%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname pgf@sh@ns@#1\endcsname\relax
  \fi
}
```

Here's working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter

\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%%
  \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}}

\newcommand\aeundefinenode[1]{%%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@ns@#1\endcsname\relax
  \else
    \typeout{===>Undefining node "#1"}%%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname pgf@sh@ns@#1\endcsname\relax
  \fi
}

\newcommand\aeundefinethesenodes[1]{%%
  \foreach \myn  in {#1}
    {%%
      \expandafter\aeundefinenode\expandafter{\myn}%%
    }%%
}

\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

%-@-(1)---------------------------------------------------------------------
There's no node \textbf{D} here, so I draw a triangle:\par
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
%  \coordinate (D) at (0,1);

  \ifnodedefined{D}
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C,D} {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C}   {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }

\end{tikzpicture}

%-@-(2)---------------------------------------------------------------------
There is a node \textbf{D} here, so I draw a square:\par
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (D) at (0,1);

  \ifnodedefined{D}
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C,D} {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C}   {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }

  \aeundefinethesenodes{A,B,C,D}
\end{tikzpicture}

%-@-(3)---------------------------------------------------------------------
There isn't supposed to be a node \textbf{D} here.  I'm expecting a
triangle, and get a triangle.\par
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,1);
%  \coordinate (D) at (0,1);

  \ifnodedefined{D}
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C,D} {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }
    {  \draw (A) foreach \myn in {B,C}   {  -- (\myn) } --cycle;  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

\newcommand\aeundefinethesenodes[1]{%%
  \foreach \myn  in {#1}
    {%%
      \expandafter\aeundefinenode\expandafter{\myn}%%
    }%%
}

\makeatother
```

[image]