# Odd behaviour drawing CDFs with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm using some code I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198383/drawing-cumulative-distribution-function-for-a-discrete-variable/198397#198397) which I modified a bit to draw cumulative distribution functions for discrete random variables.

The first plot works out great, but all subsequent plots have a point which mysteriously appears at the top left, even if the code that generates the next plot is identical. I'd like to understand exactly why.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    cdf/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
            \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*}}
                \draw plot [mark=*,mark options={fill=white}] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \ifdim\pgf@y<0pt
                    \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*,fill=white}}
                    \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
                \else
                    \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
                \fi
             \fi
        }
                {
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.7]
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xmin=-3, xmax=6,
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    cdf,
    table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
    }
]
\addplot [blue] table [y=cumulative distribution]{
x f(x)
-3 0
-2 1/6
0 1/6
2 1/3
4 1/6
5 1/6
6 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.7]
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xmin=-3, xmax=6,
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    cdf,
    table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
    }
]
\addplot [blue] table [y=cumulative distribution]{
x f(x)
-3 0
-2 1/6
0 1/6
2 1/3
4 1/6
5 1/6
6 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting output. You can see the mystery point added at the top-left of the second plot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand what the code is doing, bu the fix is to undefine the `marker` node.  For that we can use the code from [Is there a way to forget node names between TikZ pictures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178796/4301) and invoke:

```
\aeundefinenode{marker}%
```

before the next `tikzpicture`.  As per Paul Gaborit's suggestion, to be more `tikz`-like, we can invoke this with a `cdf init` style to *each* `\addplot`:

```
cdf init/.code={\aeundefinenode{marker}}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- Also see [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
  \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178778/is-there-a-way-to-forget-node-names-between-tikz-pictures (simplified version)
\def\aeundefinenode#1{%%
  \ifnodedefined{#1}{\global\expandafter\let\csname pgf@sh@ns@#1\endcsname\relax}{}%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    cdf init/.code={\aeundefinenode{marker}},
    cdf/.style={
    scatter,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
        \ifnodedefined{marker}{
            \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{marker}{center}}%
             {\pgfpoint{0}{0}}%
             \ifdim\pgf@y>0pt
                \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*}}
                \draw plot [mark=*,mark options={fill=white}] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
             \else
                \ifdim\pgf@y<0pt
                    \tikzset{options/.style={mark=*,fill=white}}
                    \draw plot [mark=*] coordinates {(marker-|0,0)};
                \else
                    \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}
                \fi
             \fi
        }
                {
            \tikzset{options/.style={mark=none}}        
        }
        \coordinate (marker) at (0,0);
        \begin{scope}[options]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.code={\end{scope}}
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.7]
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xmin=-3, xmax=6,
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    cdf,
    table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
    }
]
    \addplot [cdf init, blue] table [y=cumulative distribution]{%  <---------- Added 'cdf init'.
    x f(x)
    -3 0
    -2 1/6
    0 1/6
    2 1/3
    4 1/6
    5 1/6
    6 0
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.7]
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    jump mark left,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    xmin=-3, xmax=6,
    every axis plot/.style={very thick},
    cdf,
    table/create on use/cumulative distribution/.style={
        create col/expr={\pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{f(x)}}   
    }
]
    \addplot [cdf init, red] table [y=cumulative distribution]{%  <---------- Added 'cdf init'.
    x f(x)
    -3 0
    -2 1/6
    0 1/6
    2 1/3
    4 1/6
    5 1/6
    6 0
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I reused your solution, you can insert my answer into yours.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Good suggestion regardint using a style. Have updated the answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: You must call `cdf init` in each `\addplot` (the MWE uses only one `\addplot`). You can also simplify `\aeundefinenode` using `\ifnodedefined`.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks very much for the helpful links too.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: I don't understand why it needs to be called in each `\addplot`?

Comment: @PeterGrill The MWE in my answer shows an example: if you remove the call to `cdn init` in the red `\addplot`, you get the same bug as PO.

Comment: @PaulGaborit:  I guess it needs to be an option to `\addplot`, not the `{axis}` environment (as I did). But, you don't need it in the first `\addplot` nor in the the first `table` (as per your MWE). Will update answer.

Comment: @PeterGrill The `cdf` code assumes that the `marker` node does not exist. It is safer to guarantee it by calling `cdn init` each time.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Agreed. Updated solution to incorporate your enhancements. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterGrill Perfect. Now, I can delete mt answer.