# clash between two tikzpicture plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following tex document where I have two `tikz` pictures and they clash.

The current version of the document works for a single `tikz` picture but when I try to load in another `tikz` picture I get a weird result.

That is, running the document below should give the correct output (as below - along with another plot).

However if I comment out `\iffalse` on line 46 and then `\fi` on line 162 I obtain a different original picture.

What I want (along with having both plots in the same document and not just this single plot):

[image]

What I get after leaving `\iffalse` and `\fi` section commented out:

[image]

The first `tikz` is unaffected and its just the tree `tikz` that is affected and I cannot seem where the two pictures clash.

Document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
%%%%%%% Packages to force the plots to work %%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%% for the supervised vs unsupervised plots %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%% Random Forest %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{
  forest,
 % showframe
 }
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\tikzset{
  font=\large\sffamily\bfseries,
  red arrow/.style={
    midway,red,sloped,fill, minimum height=3cm, single arrow, single arrow head extend=.5cm, single arrow head indent=.25cm,xscale=0.3,yscale=0.15,
    allow upside down
  },
  black arrow/.style 2 args={-stealth, shorten >=#1, shorten <=#2},
  black arrow/.default={1mm}{1mm},
  tree box/.style={draw, rounded corners, inner sep=1em},
  node box/.style={white, draw=black, text=black, rectangle, rounded corners},
}
%%%%%%%%%% END: Random Forest %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%% supservises/unspuervised learning %%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% NOTE: There is a clash between this section and the random forest section %%%%

\iffalse % add a comment around the block of text - chec the end \fi
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
  group size=2 by 1,
  horizontal sep=1.5cm
  },
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
width=5cm, % <-- set size of axes
clip mode=individual, % to avoid \draws being cut off
title style={yshift=1mm, font=\bfseries\sffamily}
]

\nextgroupplot[title=Supervised learning]
\addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3, draw = black, fill = blue] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    %cluster 1
    2, 3
    3, 5
    4, 5
    3, 8
    5, 9
    3, 2
    5, 6
    6, 6
    7, 9
    10, 4
    11, 5
    9, 4
    };
    
\addplot+[red, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3, draw = black, fill = blue] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    20, 10
    21, 12
    24, 12
    25, 13
    27, 14
    22, 13
    23, 15
    25, 10
    15, 14
 };
 
 % to be able to use axis coordinates with \draw directly you need
 % \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} or a higher version
 % if that is not present, use (axis cs:4,14) instead of (4,14),
 % to specify that the values should be interpreted as axis coordinates
 \draw [dashed] (4,14) -- (25,2);
 

 
\nextgroupplot[title=Unsupervised learning]
\addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3, draw = black, fill = blue] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    %cluster 1
    2, 3
    3, 5
    4, 5
    3, 8
    5, 9
    3, 2
    5, 6
    6, 6
    7, 9
    10, 4
    11, 5
    9, 4
    };
    
\addplot+[red, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3, draw = black, fill = blue] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    20, 10
    21, 12
    24, 12
    25, 13
    27, 14
    22, 13
    23, 15
    25, 10
    15, 14
 };
 

 % save a coordinate for use later
 \coordinate (c2) at (23,12);
 
 % the blue circle is drawn inside the axis environment, and in axis coordinates
 % hence it becomes an ellipse
 \draw [blue, dashed] (6,6) circle[radius=5]; 

\end{groupplot}

% the red circle is drawn outside the axis, so actually looks like a circle,
% but the radius has no relation to the axis coordinates
\draw [red, dashed] (c2) circle[radius=1cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Supervised, Unsupervised and Reinforcement Learning}
\label{fig:supervisedUnsupervisedReinforcementLearning}
\end{figure}
\fi



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
     l sep=2em,
     s sep=2mm,
     anchor=center,
     inner sep=0,
     minimum width=1em,
     minimum height=0.5em,
     fill=blue!50,
     rectangle,
     where level=2{no edge}{}}
  [
  Training Data, node box
  [sample and feature bagging, node box, alias=bagging, above=4em,s sep=1.1cm
  [,alias=a1[[,alias=a2][]][,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[[][]]
  [,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,red!70,edge label={node[below=1ex,red arrow]{}}][,alias=a3]]]]
  [,alias=b1[,edge label={node[below=1ex,red arrow]{}}[[,alias=b2][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}]][[][[][,alias=b3]]]]
  [,phantom]
  [,phantom]
  [,alias=c1[[,alias=c2][]][,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,alias=c3][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}]][,alias=c4]]]]
  ]
  \node[tree box, fit=(a1)(a2)(a3)](t1){};
  \node[tree box, fit=(b1)(b2)(b3)](t2){};
  \node[tree box, fit=(c1)(c2)(c3)(c4)](tn){};
  \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={below right=0.5em, inner sep=0pt, font=\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}]
  \node at (t1.north west) {Tree 1};
  \node at (t2.north west) {Tree 2};
  \node at (tn.north west) {Tree $n$};
  \end{scope}
  \path (t1.south west)--(tn.south east) node[midway,below=4em, node box] (mean) {mean in regression or majority vote in classification};
  \node[below=3em of mean, node box] (pred) {prediction};
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{4mm}] (bagging) -- (t1.north);
  \draw[black arrow] (bagging) -- (t2.north);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{4mm}] (bagging) -- (tn.north);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{5mm}] (t1.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow] (t2.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{5mm}] (tn.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow] (mean) -- (pred);
  \path (t2) -- node {\dots} (tn); % <-- new node
\end{forest}
\end{center}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment on details, but it seems to be related to the fact that node names in TikZ are global (see e.g. [Is there a way to forget node names between TikZ pictures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178778/is-there-a-way-to-forget-node-names-between-tikz-pictures)). There is a named coordinate `c2` in the first `tikzpicture`, and a node with `alias=c2` in the second, and when the `fit` node is computed there is some confusion apparently.

So easy fix, change the coordinate name in the first `tikzpicture`, for example

```
\coordinate (cc2) at (23,12);

...

\draw [red, dashed] (cc2) circle[radius=1cm];
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
%%%%%%% Packages to force the plots to work %%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%% for the supervised vs unsupervised plots %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%% Random Forest %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{
  forest,
 % showframe
 }
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\tikzset{
  font=\large\sffamily\bfseries,
  red arrow/.style={
    midway,red,sloped,fill, minimum height=3cm, single arrow, single arrow head extend=.5cm, single arrow head indent=.25cm,xscale=0.3,yscale=0.15,
    allow upside down
  },
  black arrow/.style 2 args={-stealth, shorten >=#1, shorten <=#2},
  black arrow/.default={1mm}{1mm},
  tree box/.style={draw, rounded corners, inner sep=1em},
  node box/.style={white, draw=black, text=black, rectangle, rounded corners},
}
%%%%%%%%%% END: Random Forest %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%% supservises/unspuervised learning %%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% NOTE: There is a clash between this section and the random forest section %%%%

%\iffalse % add a comment around the block of text - chec the end \fi
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
  group size=2 by 1,
  horizontal sep=1.5cm
  },
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
width=5cm, % <-- set size of axes
clip mode=individual, % to avoid \draws being cut off
title style={yshift=1mm, font=\bfseries\sffamily}
]

\nextgroupplot[title=Supervised learning]
\addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3, draw = black, fill = blue] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    %cluster 1
    2, 3
    3, 5
    4, 5
    3, 8
    5, 9
    3, 2
    5, 6
    6, 6
    7, 9
    10, 4
    11, 5
    9, 4
    };
    
\addplot+[red, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3, draw = black, fill = blue] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    20, 10
    21, 12
    24, 12
    25, 13
    27, 14
    22, 13
    23, 15
    25, 10
    15, 14
 };
 
 % to be able to use axis coordinates with \draw directly you need
 % \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} or a higher version
 % if that is not present, use (axis cs:4,14) instead of (4,14),
 % to specify that the values should be interpreted as axis coordinates
 \draw [dashed] (4,14) -- (25,2);
 

 
\nextgroupplot[title=Unsupervised learning]
\addplot [blue, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3, draw = black, fill = blue] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    %cluster 1
    2, 3
    3, 5
    4, 5
    3, 8
    5, 9
    3, 2
    5, 6
    6, 6
    7, 9
    10, 4
    11, 5
    9, 4
    };
    
\addplot+[red, only marks, mark=*, mark size=3, draw = black, fill = blue] table [%
x = x, 
y = y, 
col sep = comma]{
    x, y
    20, 10
    21, 12
    24, 12
    25, 13
    27, 14
    22, 13
    23, 15
    25, 10
    15, 14
 };
 

 % save a coordinate for use later
 \coordinate (cc2) at (23,12);
 
 % the blue circle is drawn inside the axis environment, and in axis coordinates
 % hence it becomes an ellipse
 \draw [blue, dashed] (6,6) circle[radius=5]; 

\end{groupplot}

% the red circle is drawn outside the axis, so actually looks like a circle,
% but the radius has no relation to the axis coordinates
\draw [red, dashed] (cc2) circle[radius=1cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Supervised, Unsupervised and Reinforcement Learning}
\label{fig:supervisedUnsupervisedReinforcementLearning}
\end{figure}
%\fi



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
     l sep=2em,
     s sep=2mm,
     anchor=center,
     inner sep=0,
     minimum width=1em,
     minimum height=0.5em,
     fill=blue!50,
     rectangle,
     where level=2{no edge}{}}
  [
  Training Data, node box
  [sample and feature bagging, node box, alias=bagging, above=4em,s sep=1.1cm
  [,alias=a1[[,alias=a2][]][,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[[][]]
  [,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,red!70,edge label={node[below=1ex,red arrow]{}}][,alias=a3]]]]
  [,alias=b1[,edge label={node[below=1ex,red arrow]{}}[[,alias=b2][]][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}]][[][[][,alias=b3]]]]
  [,phantom]
  [,phantom]
  [,alias=c1[[,alias=c2][]][,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}[,alias=c3][,red!70,edge label={node[above=1ex,red arrow]{}}]][,alias=c4]]]]
  ]
  \node[tree box, fit=(a1)(a2)(a3)](t1){};
  \node[tree box, fit=(b1)(b2)(b3)](t2){};
  \node[tree box, fit=(c1)(c2)(c3)(c4)](tn){};
  \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={below right=0.5em, inner sep=0pt, font=\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}]
  \node at (t1.north west) {Tree 1};
  \node at (t2.north west) {Tree 2};
  \node at (tn.north west) {Tree $n$};
  \end{scope}
  \path (t1.south west)--(tn.south east) node[midway,below=4em, node box] (mean) {mean in regression or majority vote in classification};
  \node[below=3em of mean, node box] (pred) {prediction};
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{4mm}] (bagging) -- (t1.north);
  \draw[black arrow] (bagging) -- (t2.north);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{4mm}] (bagging) -- (tn.north);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{5mm}] (t1.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow] (t2.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow={5mm}{5mm}] (tn.south) -- (mean);
  \draw[black arrow] (mean) -- (pred);
  \path (t2) -- node {\dots} (tn); % <-- new node
\end{forest}
\end{center}




\end{document}
```